# I can't "paste", "rename", "cut", or "create new" files to an android phone using MTP

Tags: usb, files, android, mtp

These options are grayed out in dolphin. I do have the phone unlocked, and the "File Transfer MTP" option is enabled. Doesn't work with or without USB debugging on. I have kio-mtp, libmtp-common, libmtp-runtime, libmtp9, and mtpfs installed. I'm on Kubuntu 16.04, KDE Plasma 5.8.5 if that matters. Copying files to and from my android device as well as renaming and cutting all used to work before. If anyone can help me I'd greatly appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Not an expert with MTP but is the phone mounted read only ? Look at the output of "mount" command. Also, test if it works in non MTP mode (on my phone, swipe down from the top for connection/charge only options).

Comment: Try installing this software: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:samoilov-lex/aftl-stable; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install android-file-transfer`. Now, try copying, deleting, renaming files using `android-file-transfer`. We are doing this to find out if it's a problem with your device or with Ubuntu. You can always remove a ppa along with the packages installed with it later. Please follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) as reference to purging a ppa.

Comment: In charge only mode it asks me if my device is locked, PTP mode only shows me the camera folders but I also can not paste and rename etc. My computer doesn't recognize it MIDI mode.

Comment: Thanks Raphael, for this! Using AFT allowed me to copy to and from the device, delete, and rename. It allows me to create only folders, but that's really all I need. Dolphin can paste files into already existing folders, but that's it. This is a great work around for both my devices (Galaxy S3 and OPO). Unfortunately, Dolphin still can't do this. I don't know why is stopped working, like I said, it used to be able to.

Comment: Android File Transfer stopped working all together. It doesn't recognize my phone even though Dolphin does.